# Angular.js form parameters

Tags: angularjs

I have a form,

```
<td><input class="form-control" ng-model="contact.name"></td>
<td><input class="form-control" ng-model="contact.number"></td>
<td><input class="form-control" ng-model="contact.postcode"></td>
```

And I want postcode to be changed to all upper-case, and I want two input boxes for first name and second name, but want them to have the same ng-model. So the user enters first name and second name into separate inputs but its still just ng-model="contact.name".

Also is there a way to add non user entered data to an input e.g. I want to add the text 'Phone Number:' to the contact.number data without the user entering it.

Thank you

Comment: `the user enters first name and second name into separate inputs but its still just ng-model="contact.name"`- how do you see this ever being possible? Store it as 2 separate properties in the model and concatenate them when you need to

Comment: Well I thought possibly applying the ng-model to the parent and having two inputs within?